# Serialization Android intent

Tags: android, serialization, android-intent, deserialization

I'm trying to implement an application to serialize android intent and send it through a socket from client to server and deserialize it on the server.i try to serialize intent in client side with regular java serialization API but in the runtime it's saying that the intent  is not serializable.is there any solution to serialize intent and deserialize it? just i need to mention that i used kryo also for serialization and deserialization but again i faced error at deserialization time. is there any solution to this ?

BR,
Ra

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a new `Serializable` object and add the parts of the `Intent` that you are interested in, ie, action, bundle parameters, etc.

The `Intent` object itself is not `Serializable`.

Another approach may be to write your own `Parcel` implemenation that stores the values in another `Serializable` object type and then serialize that Object to server.  You can write an `Intent` to a `Parcel` using the `Intent.writeToParcel()` api.

Comment: thanks for the hints but do you have any idea how "Android Cloud to Device Messaging (C2DM)" can Serialize the intent and send the message to mobile device?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no experience with C2DM :(  But the C2DM docs seems to cover both sending and receiving https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/#received_data

Answer (score 0):

I've had some luck serializing intents using toUri(). Unfortunately, the corresponding deserialization method, Intent.parseUri, is unreliable and often returns null, despite the serialized data appearing to be valid.

Comment: And the uri does not contain flags or all extras.